# MYSQL stock gap prediction

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been scratching my head on a way to get this working for quite some time now, and as it's so specific I can't seem to find the answer elsewhere on StackOverflow. Any answers or suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm working to produce a report on that will inform a user of stock management and consumption. Calculating this with the values of current_stock and daily_stock_consumption is easy... But when we add shipments incoming into the process things become *very* complicated. **Getting MYSQL to return the first day that each stock reaches 0 is leaving me blank.**

For instance, let's say we are selling fruit and we have three tables fruit, fruit_sold and fruit_orders
fruit

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       fruit      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Apples     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Oranges     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       pears      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

fruit_sold

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     fruit_id     |   sold_per_day   |     day_sold     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |        101       |    1585695600    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |        445       |    1585695600    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         3        |        214       |    1585782000    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         1        |        512       |    1585782000    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

fruit_orders

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     arriving     |      fruit_id    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    1592607600    |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    1586905200    |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |    1590534000    |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |    1588287600    |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |    1593126000    |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |    1592607600    |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So far I have

```
SELECT SUM(fruit_sold.sold_per_day) / 2 AS consumption, fruit.fruit
FROM fruit_sold
LEFT JOIN fruit
ON fruit_sold.fruit_id = fruit.id
GROUP BY fruit_sold.fruit_id
```

How would I also return the number of days until the stock runs out (taking into account arriving orders and their arrival dates) for each fruit?

We want to return the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     fruit        |    consumption   |  days_until_gone |     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       apples     |        306.5     |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      oranges     |        222.5     |        16        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       pears      |        107       |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  And your dates don't look like dates to me.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've edited it to show the type of result I'm after. Dates are timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers per day using `union all`, aggregation, and window functions:

```
select fruit_id, day_sold, sum(sold_per_day), sum(orders),
       sum(sum(sold_per_day - orders)) over (partition by fruit_id order by day_sold) as net
from ((select fruit_id, day_sold, sold_per_day, 0 as orders
       from fruit_sold
      ) union all
      (select fruit_id, as day_sold, 0 as sold_per_day, count(*) as orders
       from fruit_sold
       group by fruit_id, day_sold
      ) 
     ) f
group by fruit_id, day_sold;
```

I'm not 100% how this applies to your sample data, but it seems to basically provide the information that you want.

Comment: Sadly that kicks back an error ```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by fruit_id order by day_sold) as net
from ((select fruit_id, day_sol' at line 2```

Comment: But I think without seeing the result it is along the right path.

Comment: @bowser404 . . . This requires MySQL 8+.